# Change title dynamically for MvcSiteMap?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcsitemapprovider

I am using same action method for `Add` and `Edit`. So I have an issue changing title of the breadcrumb. Now it is always showing Add Address when we do Edit. So is it possible to change `Title` dynamically. Only change is Edit address will have parameter value `AddressID`. How to change title dynamically?

```
[HttpGet]
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Add Address", ParentKey = "Addresses", Key = "AddAddress")]
public ActionResult GetEditAddress(string AddressID)
{
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to create a custom Attribute that extends off the MvcSiteMapNode.

Within your custom attribute, you will have to come up with logic to change the Title dynamically.

Comment: any online help on this?

Answer (score 4):

The [SiteMapTitle](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Using-Action-Filter-Attributes#sitemaptitle) attribute is for changing the title dynamically.

```
[SiteMapTitle("Headline")] 
public ViewResult Show(int blogId) { 

   // Headline is a string property of blog
   var blog = _repository.Find(blogId); 
   return View(blog); 
}
```

### OR

```
[SiteMapTitle("SomeKey")] 
public ViewResult Show(int blogId) { 
   ViewData["SomeKey"] = "This will be the title";

   var blog = _repository.Find(blogId); 
   return View(blog); 
}
```